# Hide Polylang metabox from the post edit sidebar

Tags: metabox, block-editor, plugin-polylang

I need to have the ability to hide the Polylang metabox from the post edit page programmatically.
I only want to show it to a few users, but hide it to people who do not have enough privileges.

There should be a possibility to do it programmatically with the wp javascript object like that

`wp.data.dispatch('core/edit-post').removeEditorPanel('polylang-metabox-id');`

I use this method for other boxes but I cannot find the ID of the Polylang box.

Any help would be appreciated.